# Can't import the named export 'ApplicationRef' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, angular8, angular-material-6

On adding any angular material in the app.module.ts, it's showing the above error.
And the console errors are the following :

compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:

1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

**angular version:**
[angular version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abTgy.png)
**angular material version:**
6.14.15
any help?

Comment: First i would update angular material version to my angular version and see if it solved the issue. Otherwise, share some code please.